# MS Access SQL Select Original From Table 1 Join Table 2 Select Matching

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a list of transactions from the bank in the table `Master`, each with a unique `masterID`. These transactions are then split into journal entries by the users, which are stored in the table `Master_Split`. The `Master_Split` table has a foreign key field named `import_Master_ID` which connects the two tables together.

I'm trying to create a query that selects the `Master` record, and the split records in the same format.

Originally I had used a right join, as only the split entries were required. However, now the requirements have changed, and I'm not sure what technique/keywords I should be researching. You can see the desired output in the third table.

Any guidance, even point me in the right direction would be appreciated. Please let me know if anything about the question is unclear, and thank you advance for any help.

```
SELECT 
M.[masterID], M.[OrigAcctNum], S.[NewAcctNum], S.[PostAmnt]
FROM Master M
RIGHT JOIN Master_Split S ON M.[masterID] = S.[import_Master_ID]`
```

`Master table
+----------+---------+----------+
| masterID | AcctNum | PostAmnt |
+----------+---------+----------+
| 1        | 99999   | 150      |
+----------+---------+----------+
| 2        | 88888   | 200      |
+----------+---------+----------+`

`Master_Split
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| import_master_ID | SplitAcct | SplitAmnt |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1                | 12345     | -50       |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1                | 54321     | -100      |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2                | 11111     | -175      |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2                | 22222     | -25       |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+`

`Result
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| masterID | OrigAcctNum | NewAcctNum | PostAmnt | Status |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| 1        | 99999       | 99999      | 150      | Orig   |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| 1        | 99999       | 12345      | -50      | Split  |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| 1        | 99999       | 54321      | -100     | Split  |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| 2        | 88888       | 88888      | 200      | Orig   |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| 2        | 88888       | 11111      | -175     | Split  |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| 2        | 88888       | 22222      | -25      | Split  |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+`

Comment: What is your desired result? How has requirements changed?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear. But the desired output is the third table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION ALL will give you both sets of information in a single result set:

```
SELECT 
M.[masterID], M.[OrigAcctNum], M.[NewAcctNum], M.[PostAmnt], 'Orig' AS [Status]
FROM Master M
UNION ALL
SELECT 
M2.[masterID], M2.[OrigAcctNum], S.[NewAcctNum], S.[PostAmnt], 'Split' AS [Status]
FROM Master M2
RIGHT JOIN Master_Split S ON M2.[masterID] = S.[import_Master_ID]`
```

Comment: Combing the union and right join, didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do the job.. sorry written in not pad with 5 mins to go before heading home..

```
    select * from 
    (
            select 
                masterID as ID,  AcctNum  as OrigAcctNum,  AcctNum  as NewAcctNum,  PostAmnt,  'Orig' as Status
            from Master 
        union all
            select 
                ms.import_master_ID  as ID,  m.AcctNum  as OrigAcctNum,  ms.SplitAcct as NewAcctNum,  ms.SplitAmnt as PostAmnt,  'Split' as Status
            from Master_Split ms
                join Master m on m.masterID = ms.import_master_ID
            where
    )
    order by ID
```